# discord bot missing permission but granted admin access

Tags: discord

I'm trying to hit the /guilds/{guildId} endpoint, and I've created a bot and installed it on the server I'm trying to access and even granted it admin access, but I'm still getting a "missing access" error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the guild have two factor authentication enabled, you'll need to enable it on your account as well. That is, the account under which the bot application is registered needs to have two factor authentication enabled.

Comment: nope, no MFA on the channel

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Are you using a bearer token by chance?

Comment: @Anu6is Nope, using the bot token and never got it resolved... It's a bummer too cause this is the last thing I need to deploy to prod :-(

Comment: What about other endpoints? Have you tried wrappers like discord.js?

Comment: I seem to have run into the same issue. Weird as it worked previously with a previous "discord app" (I made a second app for development purposes). I wonder if it's a bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JS Manage Roles Permission Missing even though bot is admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360928/discord-js-manage-roles-permission-missing-even-though-bot-is-admin)

Answer (score 8):

In this case, Error 403 either means that the Bot is not in a guild with that id or that there is no guild with the id you provided in the URL.

Make sure, you copied the id of the correct server.

Answer (score 2):

Double check if you are using the correct token and if you're posting to the right guild.

If the bot has administrator, it simply has access to all channels. This error means that the bot user either does not have permission or is not in that guild.

Comment: If the authorization fails, there would be http status code `401: Unauthorized`.

Comment: That's true, but maybe you have 2 different bots and are using the wrong one