# Discord JS Manage Roles Permission Missing even though bot is admin

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

My Discord bot isn't adding the role to the user who uses the command.

My Code:

```
if (userCmd.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}verify`) {
  if (message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Rookie' && message.channel.id === '71xxxxxxxxxxx10')) {
  const rookieRole = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Rookie')
  const proRole = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Pro')

  try {
    if (message.guild.me.permissions.missing('MANAGE_ROLES')) return message.reply('I\'m missing permissions.');
    if (message.author.id === message.guild.ownerID) return message.reply('I can\'t change your ROLE.');

    message.member.roles.add(proRole)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

[image]

I tried everything possible:
Removed and added the bot with all permissions again, moved the BOT ROLE at top in the hierarchy of roles, etc.

[image]
`DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

[image]

**EDIT:**
*For no reason, using only `message.member.roles.add(proRole)` makes my bot work :v*

Comment: Is discord.js returning any error?

Comment: @NullDev Tbh it is returning the MISSING PERMISSIONS Line

Comment: @NullDev It was `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions` before I add the `console.log()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bot's highest role must be higher than the role you need to assign in the role list, otherwise, it won't be able to give it to anyone.

Comment: I did :D No one else has more power than the BOT. Bot role has Admin too. BOT ROLE is at the TOP MOST position in the roles tab but it isn't working.

Comment: I added a screenshot of that too... It's above the Rookie Role

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've added another answer, I hope this will help

Comment: The solution works. But where is this documented? An official source for this would be great.

Comment: That's a default Discord limitation, which apparently was extended over to bot accounts as well

Comment: @Tenclea where is that other answer?

Comment: It was deleted some time ago, since it was irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 26):

I just came across this same problem, and nothing I did was helping out. 
Until, I came across a reddit post, 3 years old. That did the trick.

> In server settings, literally drag the bots role above the roles it will be assigning.

**Credit:** [Reddit Comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/7ttd58/get_missing_permissions_when_trying_to_add_a_role/dtf3ouh?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: oh my god, same. I've been bashing my head against this for hours and hours. i cannot believe how dumb this solution is. but thank you!

Comment: omg you saved me

Comment: this has been huge issue for me.. thanks