# How do I make a role in Discord.JS that is a bit higher than other roles on the Role Hierarchy?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Sort of a follow up to my other question but, I am making a slash command that'd make a role with customisable permissions, customisable colours, and a customisable place up in the Role Hierarchy.

I've seen that it **isn't** possible to make a role that is higher up on the Role Hierarchy if the bot is lower than the role you want to put it above, unless done by a member with MANAGE_ROLES and a high role but, is it actually possible to make the bot do this or not?

***Any ideas?***

P.S: I have seen bots that, upon invited, request that you put their role at the top of the list. I might make something like that for my bot.

Comment: sorry for not reading  the question properly though, is this helpful to you? (well, you can't create roles, you can only add roles to members)-> [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360928/discord-js-manage-roles-permission-missing-even-though-bot-is-admin) , [link2](https://maah.gitbooks.io/discord-bots/content/getting-started/roles-and-channels-permissions.html)

Comment: Well, you can create roles and add roles to members, please research. I want to add a role/make a role that is higher up on the Role Hierarchy however if the bot role is lower than the role I want to add to the user, it won't add.

Comment: IDK if i undrestood you correctly, but it isn't possible (for both, user and bot (the only exception is server owner, that on background always have higher role then everyone else)) to create/manage role, that is higher than/equal to your highest role. This is just discord works and you can't bypass it unless you use the strategy mentioned in your post, that the bot asks admin for high enough role.

Comment: Yeah I thought so... oh well, I better get working on that feature then :/